# How to CONCATENATE a VLOOKUP and have the lookup take place without an CR after a copy and paste value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, concatenation

```
A   B   C           

=VLOOKUP(C1,B6:C8,2)    =VLOOKUP(C1,B6:C8,2)    =VLOOKUP(C1,B6:C8,2)
=VLOOKUP(D1,B6:C8,2)    =VLOOKUP(D1,B6:C8,2)    =VLOOKUP(D1,B6:C8,2)
=VLOOKUP(A1,B6:C8,2)    =VLOOKUP(A1,B6:C8,2)    =VLOOKUP(A1,B6:C8,2)

A   FF              
B   GG              
C   HH
```

The last column is made using copy and paste value. I need it to execute, do the lookup, without my
needing to do a CR. I am doing thousands of cells and do not want to do each CR. Also must not use
VB or Macro.

Comment: I get that you want to combine the `VLOOKUP` formulas, but the body of the question doesn't make sense. Can you clarify what you are attempting so we can better understand how to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but the easiest way to concatenate multiple lookups is to use the ampersand '&'.

e.g.

```
=vlookup(C1,B6:C8,2)&vlookup(C1,B6:C8,2)&vlookup(C1,B6:C8,2)
```

you could add a space by using
`&" "&` instead of the single ampersand or a dash and spaces `&" - "&`

Also not sure why you are having to do a CR